# undef variable from "if" condition

Tags: perl

I have a problem condition in Perl. I hope someone can help me.

```
my $bCommType = 'none';

my %commTypes = (
    'none'              => '0',
    'public'            => '1',
    'custom_percentage' => '2',
    'custom_permeg'     => '2',
    'custom_flat'       => '2',
);

my %rateTypes = (
    'custom_percentage' => '%',
    'custom_permeg'     => '$',
    'custom_flat'       => 'FLAT',
    'none'              => 'none',
);

my $commrate = $rateTypes{$bCommType} if ( $commTypes{$bCommType} == 2 );
```

my output in `$commrate` is `undef`, can someone help me identify the issue?

Comment: What is your question? You forgot to ask one. What do you want us to identify?

Comment: my $commrate = $rateTypes{$bCommType} if ($commTypes{$bCommType} == 2); I am getting an undef value in my variable.

Comment: [It's called Perl, not PERL.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Name) :)

Comment: You still haven't actually asked a question. You're just stating facts.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a conditional declaration. That's deprecated. Perl is probably giving you a warning (you are using `use warnings`, right?).

Move the declaration into its own line, provide a default, and do the assignment with the condition in a new line.

```
my $commrate = 'default'; # it's not clear which %commTypes is the default
$commrate = $rateTypes{$bCommType} if ($commTypes{$bCommType} == 2);
```

You need to provide a default or starting value because new variables in Perl always start out as `undef`.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that.

Comment: then, how do i pass the conditional output to the commrate variable?

Comment: @JonjonNegrite sorry, I forgot the assignment. Updated. The important parts are that 1) you need to declare the variable before you conditionally assign something, and 2) you need to assign something so it does not start as `undef`.

Comment: my %commTypes=( 'none'        => '0',
              'public'      => '1', 
              'custom_percentage' => '2', 
              'custom_permeg'   => '2', 
              'custom_flat'   => '2',  
              ); this the commType

Comment: @JonjonNegrite that's a list of different types. Which one is the default? I think what you really want to do is `$commrate = $rateType{ $rateTypes{ $bCommType } };`. Set `$commrate` to the rate that's behind the type number that's in `$bCommType`. BTW, your variable names are not very good. We usually don't use camel case in Perl. Try to pick very verbose names for your vars, so it's easy to understand what they do.

Comment: it is not my code, i am just debugging it also for my friend. i just don't understand this my $commrate = $rateTypes{$bCommType} if ($commTypes{$bCommType} == 2); where is returning the undef

Comment: @JonjonNegrite that line does two things: 1) it creates a new variable `$commrate`. New variables start out as `undef` if you don't assign something. 2) it assigns a value **if the condition is met**. So if not, it's not assigned. But that syntax is deprecated. That means you should not use it because it will be removed in the future. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Deprecated-use-of-my()-in-false-conditional

Answer (score 2):

You set `$commrate` to `$rateTypes{$bCommType}` if the value of `$commTypes{$bCommType}` is 2. But `$bCommType` is `none` and `$commTypes{none}` is zero, so the assignment doesn't happen and `$commrate` is left undefined

That is the root of your problem, but aside from this, you shouldn't declare a variable conditionally. It does all sorts of strange and undefined things if you try. As **simbabque** has said, you need to declare the variable separately and make just the assigmnent conditional, but in this case the result will be the same for the reason I described above

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way of using a conditional declaration. This method will work whether if you are working with Perl, JavaScript, Java or PHP. Where I declared the condition, the statement before the question mark is the condition. The value right after the question mark is the value that will be assigned to the variable when the condition evaluates to be true. The value after the column is the value that will be assigned to the variable if the statement evaluates to be false.

```
use strict;
my $bCommType = 'none';

my %commTypes = (
    'none'              => '0',
    'public'            => '1',
    'custom_percentage' => '2',
    'custom_permeg'     => '2',
    'custom_flat'       => '2',
);

my %rateTypes = (
     'custom_percentage' => '%',
     'custom_permeg'     => '$',
     'custom_flat'       => 'FLAT',
     'none'              => 'none',
);

my $commrate = $commTypes{$bCommType} == 2? $rateTypes{$bCommType} : "false value";

print $commrate;
```